# Phaser rectangle strage behavior

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I've created [codepen](http://codepen.io/guruyaya/pen/vgwPGG) to show this bug.

The update function:

```
  update: function(){
  this.timeBar.width = this.timeBar.width - 1;
```

is set to change the width only. However, viewing it on chrome, it seem to change position too. Is this a bug, or is it just somthing I didn't take into account, while writing this code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thx remove, link format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be somewhat complicated using Graphics, but I found an example using BitmapData:

```
  create: function(){
    var bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(300, 40);
        bmd.ctx.beginPath();
        bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 300, 80);
        bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#00685e';
        bmd.ctx.fill();

    var bglife = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, bmd);
    bglife.anchor.set(0.5);

    bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(280, 30);
    bmd.ctx.beginPath();
        bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 300, 80);
        bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
        bmd.ctx.fill();

    this.widthLife = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height);
    this.totalLife = bmd.width;

    this.life = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX - bglife.width/2 + 10, this.game.world.centerY, bmd);
    this.life.anchor.y = 0.5;
    this.life.cropEnabled = true;
    this.life.crop(this.widthLife);

    this.scheduler = this.game.time.events.loop(1500, this.cropLife, this);
  },

  cropLife: function(){
    if(this.widthLife.width <= 0){
      this.widthLife.width = this.totalLife;
      this.scheduler.stop();
    }
    else{
      this.game.add.tween(this.widthLife).to( { width: (this.widthLife.width - (this.totalLife / 10)) }, 200, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true);
    }
  },

  update: function(){
    this.life.updateCrop();
  }
```

**[You can see the discussion in detail here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3985-health-bars/#comment-81718)**

Comment: I acctually solved this some other way, by deleting and redrawing graphics, but thanks for your help